# <option> if defined as part of array not being shown in materialize / react

Tags: reactjs, select, materialize

So I am new to react and materialize. What I am trying to do is to generate a simple dropdown.
I am sourcing the data via fetch and storing the  in an array

```
let fruits = fruitList.map((fruit,i) => <option key={i} value={fruit.name}> {fruit.name} </option>);
```

I then add this to the state with this.setState(...)

The issue that I am having is that following code does not show any  from the fruitList but only the explicitly defined ones, i.e. in the case below, only Banana

```
    <div className="my_container" >
      <div className="input-field col s12">
        <select searchable='List of Fruites' onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="" disabled >Choose your Fruit</option>
          {this.state.fruits}
          <option value="Banana" >Banana</option> */}
        </select>
        <label>Materialize Select</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Don't store React components in state, store just the data and *then* map it to the JSX you want to render. What is `this.state.countryNames`? Seems unrelated to fruits.

Comment: @Drew Reese: Sorry for this. corrected it in the meantime. forgot to adjust it when I simplified the code for this post

Comment: What is `fruitList`? Have you just tried mapping it to options normally in the JSX?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `fruitList` array in the `state`.
And in the code block, you can use it as:

```html
 <div className="my_container" >
   <div className="input-field col s12">
     <select searchable='List of Fruites' onChange={this.handleChange}>
       <option value="" disabled >Choose your Fruit</option>
       {this.state.fruitList && this.state.fruitList.map((fruit,i) => <option key={i} value={fruit.name}> {fruit.name} </option>)}
       <option value="Banana" >Banana</option>
     </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

There were some typos.

Comment: That I was already doing. sorry that was a typo in the code when I simplified for this post. The code that you posted did unfortunately not work

Comment: @greenhorn87 It is working fine, I think. Please ref:  https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-ritchie-0027q?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `fruitList` is a passed prop or some static data, but you should avoid storing React components in state. It is also a React anti-pattern to store passed props into local component state. Just render out the content directly in the JSX.

```
<div className="my_container">
  <div className="input-field col s12">
    <label>
      <select searchable='List of Fruites' onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="" disabled>Choose your Fruit</option>
        {fruitList.map(({ name }) => (
          <option key={name} value={name}>{name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      Materialize Select
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
const fruitList = [{ name: 'Apple' }, { name: 'Pear' }, { name: 'Orange' }];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div className="my_container">
    <div className="input-field col s12">
      <label>
        <select searchable='List of Fruites'>
          <option value="" disabled>Choose your Fruit</option>
          {fruitList.map(({ name }) => (
            <option key={name} value={name}>{name}</option>
          ))}
          <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
        </select>
        Materialize Select
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```